# Perl 6 and print columns

Tags: perl, raku

Does Perl 6 have something equivalent to the [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::GCString)'s `columns` method?

Perl 5 example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use 5.10.0;
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use Unicode::GCString;

my $s = '合'; # U+5408

say length $s;      # 1

my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new( $s );
say $gcs->columns;  # 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl6 has builtin Unicode support, with native Uni and NFC/NFD/NFKC/NFKD normalized types.

What I vaguely understand is, that the Unicode::GCString::columns method determines eastasian language linebreaking support.
合 is composed of 2 "syllables" (they call it "grapheme clusters") on top of each other, thus 2 columns.

That being said, perl6 internally (on the MoarVM level) has access to the unicode database where the linebreaking properties are stored, but to my knowledge there's currently no module, like Unicode::UCD available to make the East_Asian_Width properties available for something like a Unicode::GCString.

On the other side, converting Unicode::LineBreak to perl6 looks easy enough, accessing the sombok library via NativeCall.

Comment: Upvoted because Reini is doing the key thing -- doing what it takes to try to usefully move this issue forward. I'm posting this comment first to counter balance the things I'm going to say next.

Comment: A grapheme is what a human would typically call one character. So 合 is one grapheme, not two. Thus, using a recent Rakudo, `say "合".chars.say' returns 1.

Comment: The thing underlying the columns function under discussion is "the concept of an inherent width of a [east asian] character. This width takes on either of two values: narrow or wide." (from http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/tr11-29.html)

Comment: The East Asian Width Property Data File associated with UAX #11, namely EastAsianWidth.txt, is not mentioned in the MoarVM script that processes such files (https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/tools/ucd2c.pl). This suggests to me that the East Asian Width annex is currently completely ignored by MoarVM and thus, presumably, Rakudo (the Perl 6 compiler of note).

Comment: Exactly, 合 is one grapheme, but the linebreak property clusters it into 2 columns. The sombok library does this.

I'm not sure if this needs to be in MoarVM core, it rather looks like a perfect extension module, as in perl5. I added it to the list of wanted perl6 modules. https://github.com/perl6/perl6-most-wanted/blob/master/most-wanted/modules.md

Comment: Imo "clusters it into 2 columns" is confusing because you're using the word "clusters" in a manner that's not only unrelated to, but actually in conflict with, its use in the Unicode standard, where it's used in relation to "grapheme clusters". More importantly your original answer (still) suggests "syllables [are] grapheme clusters". That's worse than confusing because it's plain 'ol wrong.

Comment: This property isn't (only) about line breaking. From UAX #11: "Layout and line breaking (to cite only two examples) in East Asian context show systematic variations depending on the value of this East_Asian_Width property."

Comment: Afaict, the columns function returns the maximum East Asian Width of the individual codepoints in a given sequence of combining codepoints (typically a grapheme). I'm guessing this function exists to solve an issue mentioned in UAX #11: "Decomposing a character, and applying the East_Asian_Width to a base character and combining marks separately does not yield the expected values."

Comment: raiph: Probably contrary to you I actually learned some asian languages like hangul and japanese, and in those languages (in fact most east asian based languages)  "the basic unit for grapheme clusters for indic and south-east asian scripts is the syllable" - https://www.w3.org/International/reviews/0801-uax29/ (Conjunct clusters)

Insisting that I am wrong would require some effort to argue what exactly is wrong in my explanation.

Comment: /o\ Thanks for being gentle. :) The link you sent was helpful. I got confused about "grapheme cluster". Do you agree with: 1) 合 is one *extended* grapheme cluster (EGC). 2) The East Asian Width property assumes use of *tailored* grapheme clusters (TGC). 3) These particular TGCs would cluster based on syllables. 4) The East Asian Width property is about figuring out a setting of 1 or 2 for each syllable. 5) Rakudo/MoarVM does not support *any* TGCs, just EGCs. 6) CPAN is in pretty good shape, Unicode wise. 7) One can usefully use Unicode modules from CPAN in Rakudo. 8) You were right all along?